# How to pass GeoJSON object to ST_GeomFromGeoJSON

Tags: python, postgis, postgresql, geojson

As shown in the below posted code, I am trying to print and pass the value of `feature['geometry']` to the method `postgreSQLHelper.queryPostgreSQLForGeoJSON`
the output of the log-statement:

```
DEBUG:root:feature['geometry']: {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[[6.69223420722764, 51.1329165124371], [6.69222819326484, 51.1329081193748], [6.69221180776184, 51.1329013203209], [6.69219149698336, 51.1329073049609], [6.69217949340067, 51.1329244260894], [6.69217956546811, 51.1329430447612], [6.69218526127669, 51.1329578171713], [6.692200130301, 51.1329606289999], [6.69220511560768, 51.1329581192089], [6.69221372090576, 51.1329518135339], [6.69222707128915, 51.132939215911], [6.69223420722764, 51.1329165124371]]]}
```

which is a valid GeoJSON format,
but when I pass the object `features['geometry']` to the method I receive an error:

```
self.cur.execute(sql,bindings)
```

psycopg2.errors.SyntaxFehler: FEHLER: Syntaxfehler bei "type"
ZEILE 1: SELECT ST_AsText(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{'type': 'Polygon', 'co...

Why, despite the fact that the GeoJSON object is well formatted, does this error appear, and how do I fix it?

I pass the code:

```
for feature in featuresArray[0:1]:
    logger.debug("feature['geometry']: {0}".format(feature['geometry']))
    postgreSQLHelper.queryPostgreSQLForGeoJSON(feature['geometry'])
```

Comment: What is `postgreSQLHelper.queryPostgreSQLForGeoJSON`? Some docs? Did not find it anywhere in any library on the web

Comment: it is my own class as helper and wrapper to perform some postgis queries

Comment: Show us this part, plz. Also `SELECT ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[6.69223420722764, 51.1329165124371], [6.69222819326484, 51.1329081193748], [6.69221180776184, 51.1329013203209], [6.69219149698336, 51.1329073049609], [6.69217949340067, 51.1329244260894], [6.69217956546811, 51.1329430447612], [6.69218526127669, 51.1329578171713], [6.692200130301, 51.1329606289999], [6.69220511560768, 51.1329581192089], [6.69221372090576, 51.1329518135339], [6.69222707128915, 51.132939215911], [6.69223420722764, 51.1329165124371]]]}')` works

Comment: Difference = single quotes replaced by double quotes in the JSON input keys

Comment: In your error `ST_AsText(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{'type': 'Polygon',` so there is at least an escape related error

Comment: @ThomasG77 it is the output of the object. how can i modify the object to repalce single qoutes with doubled

Comment: JSON is quite literal is its formatting requirements, as the question posted two hour earlier addressed.

Answer (score 1):

A correction to be able to execute the code. Adapt to your own code

```py
import json
import psycopg2

# Below = hard coded value from your feature['geometry']
mygeom = {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[[6.69223420722764, 51.1329165124371], [6.69222819326484, 51.1329081193748], [6.69221180776184, 51.1329013203209], [6.69219149698336, 51.1329073049609], [6.69217949340067, 51.1329244260894], [6.69217956546811, 51.1329430447612], [6.69218526127669, 51.1329578171713], [6.692200130301, 51.1329606289999], [6.69220511560768, 51.1329581192089], [6.69221372090576, 51.1329518135339], [6.69222707128915, 51.132939215911], [6.69223420722764, 51.1329165124371]]]}

with psycopg2.connect("connexionstring") as conn: 
    with conn.cursor() as cur:             
        cur.execute("SELECT ST_AsText(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(%s));", (json.dumps(mygeom),)) 
        row = cur.fetchone() 
        print(row)
```